# Sass global variables and mixins not working

Tags: vue.js, sass, vite

I've set up a project using Vue 3.2.33 and Vite 2.9.5

When I try to access any global variable or mixin from within any vue component, I get an undefined error. This problem doesn't occur in scss files.

The import itself seems working correctly because any css rules in it are working.

vite.config.ts:

```js
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'url';

import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [vue()],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
        },
    },
    css: {
        preprocessorOptions: {
            scss: {
                additionalData: '@use "@/styles/variables";',
            },
        },
    },
});
```

src/styles/_variables.scss:

```scss
// breakpoints
$breakpoints: (
    "sm": 576px,
    "md": 768px,
    "lg": 992px,
    "xl": 1200px,
    "xxl": 1400px,
);

@mixin test {
    border: 3px solid red;
}
```

Example use:

```scss
<style scoped lang="scss">
@use 'sass:map';

.container {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    @include test; // <- undefined

    &--fluid {
        max-width: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
}

$widths: (
    'sm': 540px,
    'md': 720px,
    'lg': 960px,
    'xl': 1140px,
    'xxl': 1320px,
);

@each $breakpoint, $width in $widths {
    @media (min-width: map.get($breakpoints, $breakpoint)) { // <- $breakpoints undefined
        .container {
            max-width: $width;
        }
    }
}
</style>
```

Comment: it's unknown at which point the problem occurs. Did you try to add use @/styles/variables explicitly?

Comment: Yes, I've tried

Comment: Your file is named `_variables.scss` (and not sure where that's even located), but your import is `@/styles/variables`. How is that reconciled?

Comment: The problem is not with the path, since basic css rules are properly imported. The problem is that the sass-specific code like variables or mixins is not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've managed to "fix" the issue. Turns out, when I replace all `@use` rules for file imports, the sass code is imported correctly and works. But this produces a new problem as the `@import` rules cannot be placed before `@use`, so I had to remove the `additionalData` key from config and include the imports manually.

Answer (score 4):

use

```css
@import
```

in your vite config instead of

```css
@use
```

`vite.config.ts`:

```js
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [vue()],
    css: {
        preprocessorOptions: {
            scss: {
                additionalData: '@import "./src/styles/variables.scss";',
            },
        },
    },
});
```

keep in mind that you cannot import the same file `variables.scss` again in your `main.ts` file otherwise, you will get this error

```scss
[sass] This file is already being loaded.
```

by the way, you can also import the `scss` file in every single component manually as you mentioned but that would be really tedious so using a global import in `preprocessorOptions` in `vite.config.ts` is a much better option for files used globally like a `variables.scss` file.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't you tried to add `as *` to your `additionalData` value?
So that the line would look like this:

```
scss: {
    additionalData: '@use "@/styles/variables" as *;',
  },
```

This worked for me with scss mixins and I prefer this solution because using `@import` instead of `@use` here indeed forces me to swap all `@use`s to `@import`s in Vue component (because of "@import rules cannot be placed before @use" error), which has some drawbacks.